# display commas instead of periods

Tags: mysql, django, django-templates

in my sql table I have decimal data with dot as a separator but the display in my page is done with commas

I would like to display them with dot

in my settings i have this

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "fr-fr"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

my models

```
class VilleStation(models.Model):
    nomVille = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cp = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
```

in the templates i have this

```
{% for c in object_list %}                
{{c.nomVille}}
{{c.adresse}}
{{c.cp}}
{{c.latitude}}
{{c.longitude}}
{% endfor %}
```

thank

Comment: I found a solution with regular expressions in my view. To replace the comma with a period. With import re, regex = r'^(\(\d+),(\d\))'. But if anyone has a simpler solution, thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there's a tag to unlocalise things. I might be wrong but let me check. There is a good answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a whirl, as per the docs, you can turn off number localisation like so:

```
{{  value|floatformat:"3u"  }}
```

**What do the docs say?**

> Output is always localized (independently of the {% localize off %} tag) unless the argument passed to floatformat has the u suffix, which will force disabling localization.

**Be aware of the following note further down the page:**

> Changed in Django 4.0:
> floatformat template filter no longer depends on the USE_L10N setting and always returns localized output.

**And subsequently:**

> The u suffix to force disabling localization was added

Please see the documentation regarding the [floatformat template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat)

Comment: thanks Swift, this solution works to display dots for decimals in my contry (France ). I still kept, in addition, the solution with a regex, for other operations.

Comment: no problems, I would recommend trying to use the template tag as this can be re-used in any template or HTML snippet, whereas your regex solution, while I imagine it is perfectly fine, it probably requires more customisation than you really need. Simpler is always better.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal separator is controlled by two settings in Django settings:

First one is DECIMAL_SEPARATOR (Default: '.')

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#decimal-separator

And second one: USE_L10N (Default: True)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#use-l10n

in your case use `USE_L10N=False`

Comment: But then nothing will be translated? And he might want to only disable localisation for these numbers because they're lat and long, which is always expected in a specific format.

Comment: Translations are controlled by `USE_I18N` and he set deciaml places in DecimalField settings so I assume he knows what he is doing

Comment: I'm not suggesting what you said isn't true, im saying that it might not be the right solution.

Comment: thank Bartosz, USE_L10N=False also works. I believe that in my particular case, a regular expression in my class in views.py with the RE module is the best solution. thank you both for your solutions